# Increase DPI of copy/pasted plots from RStudio

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

When I copy-paste a plot image from RStudio, the resolution is poor likely dpi=150. I know that I can save images with higher resolution with `ggsave(dpi=300)` but this adds another step to the workflow. Can I change a setting in RStudio so that my copied images are higher res?

[image]

Comment: An additional line of code in an R script file is an additional step to the workflow, but right-clicking an image and saving manually is not?

Comment: ggsave(), open file location, then drag image to Google Slides is considerably more interruption than right-click copy/paste